# TensorFlow FullyConnected Tutorial: How are the trained weights used for Eval and Test?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, training-data

I've been looking through the TensorFlow [FullyConnected](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py) tutorial. This also uses the helper code [mnist.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py)

I understand the code but for one nagging piece. After training the Neural Net, the weights obtained from training should be used to evaluate the precision of the model on the Validation (and Test) data. However, I don't see that being done anywhere.

Infact, this is the only thing I see in *fully_connected_feed.py*

```
    # Evaluate against the validation set.
    print('Validation Data Eval:')
    do_eval(sess,
            eval_correct,
            images_placeholder,
            labels_placeholder,
            data_sets.validation)

    # Evaluate against the test set.
    print('Test Data Eval:')
    do_eval(sess,
            eval_correct,
            images_placeholder,
            labels_placeholder,
            data_sets.test)
```

the `do_eval()` function seems to be passed a parameter `eval_correct` which seems to be recalculating the logits again on this new data. I've been playing around with TF for a while now but I'm baffled by this code. Any thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow creates a graph with the weights and biases. Roughly speaking while you train this neural net the weights and biases get changed so it produces expected outputs. The line 131 in *fully_connected_feed.py* (`with tf.Graph().as_default():`) is used to tell TensorFlow to use the default graph. Therefore every line in the training loop including the calls of the `do_eval()` function use the default graph. Since the weights obtained from training are not resetted before evaluation they are used for it.

`eval_correct` is the operation used instead of the training operation to just evaluate the neural net without training it. This is important because otherwise the neural net would be trained to them which would result in distorted (too good) results.

Comment: This helps! Thanks much. Can you clarify this a little more please? I am looking at mnist.py and the `inference()` function.  Looking at lines 57 through 64. Are you saying that lines 58 (for weights) and 62 (for biases) won't be executed but Line 64 would be? It has to execute as the relu has to process the validation and test data.

Comment: Glad that it helped :) The `inference()` function just builds the graph and is called just once. The difference between the evaluation and the training is that in the evaluation the `eval_correct` operation (line 148) in *fully_connected_feed.py* is run instead of the `training_op` (line 145). Look at *mnist.py* (lines 103-150) to see the corresponding functions. The `training_op` uses the optimizer to change the weights and biases while the `eval_correct` op just counts the correct predictions made by the neural net.

Comment: I get that. What I'm struggling with is that `eval_correct = mnist.evaluation(logits, labels_placeholder)` calls the `evaluation` function with the logits as arguments. And logits are assigned on line 137 as `logits = mnist.inference(images_placeholder,FLAGS.hidden1,FLAGS.hidden2)`. So the `inference` function has to be called even in the case of validation and testing - without it the new logits will not be calculated for validation and test. Am I thinking of this all wrong?

Comment: The line 137 creates the graph which is a series of mathematical operations. These ops require variables i.e. the weights and biases. Using `logits` as argument doesn't mean that the graph gets build again but that the way of computing the guesses is given. To compute anything it is important to start a session and use the `sess.run()`as in line 185. The `feed_dict` is important to give serve the inputs (images) to the graph. You can think of the `evaluation` or `training` function as an added math operation to the graph which uses the result from the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the patience with me! I see a `true_count += sess.run(eval_correct, feed_dict=feed_dict)` on line 118 which will get called for the validation and test datasets. I think I now understand that TF only recomputes parts of the graph (and not the whole graph). However, new logits have to be calculated for Validation and Test datasets and the only place that recomputes the logits is in the `inference` function in minst.py on line 82.  So.. are you saying that the weights and biases will NOT get reinitialized but the logits will get recomputed for the Valid \ Test data?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. The logits are the output of the graph (the digit written in the given pictures). Therefore they are different for every batch that gets computed. While training the values of the weights and biases get changed a bit every trainstep to get a better result which means that the loss gets smaller and smaller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117116/discussion-between-shanbhag-and-b1t0).